Stop Gboard from changing the text I type
I recently acquired a Motorola Moto G34 with Android 14 installed. The keyboard is Gboard, without any add-ons or extra languages. As I type, on any application, the keyboard keeps modifying the words, especially capitalising the first character and changing singular to plural, but also adds strange accents, sometimes just replacing the word for another.
In the Settings menu, all I can find is the spell checker, which is switched off. In any case, whatever the keyboard software is doing, it certainly isn't spell-checking. I suspect it is some kind of "AI" meant to help, that does anything but.
How can I stop Gboard from changing the text I type?

According to the online manual, looks like the default keyboard is Gboard. Does it look like this on Play Store (or otherwise, is this keyboard installed)?

@AndrewT. Yes, Gboard is listed as installed in the Play Store.

You can click on the settings icon at the top of the keyboard. Open the keyboard like this:

Click on the Text correction settings like this.

Then try turning off  Smart compose setting or Auto-capitalization settings.

If this doesn't fix the issue, go back to the main settings of the keyboard (where Text correction settings are present) and click on Languages. Check that your language is installed and is at the top of the list of languages.

I can't find the Smart compose setting in the keyboard. The other options you refer are switched off. I write messages in several different languages, "my language" does not really apply in this context.

The information gathered from the discussion so far makes it clear this is a problem with a particular application (Gboard) and not a system issue. The spell-checking setting is inactive system wide.
Therefore a solution is to simply install a different keyboard software. In my case I have been using Unexpected Keyboard since yesterday and it is pretty competent.
